# UIImage at last point of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a UIImage at last point of UIBezierPath like the image bellow:

[Circle Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9fOh.png)

Code:

```
let consume = 0.25
let x = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
let y = self.frame.size.height / 2.0
let radius = (frame.size.width - 10) / 2.0
let startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI * (-1/2))
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 - M_PI/2 * consume)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)

circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
circleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0;

let image = UIImage(named: "myCoolImage")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
// coordX and coordY must be at last point of UIBezierPath
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: coordX, y: coordY, width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
self.addSubview(imageView)
```

I've tried the following:

```
let coordX: CGFloat = cos(endAngle) * radius
let coordY: CGFloat = sin(endAngle) * radius
```

Result:
[Positive coordX and coordY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95HhL.png)

The main problem is how to calculate the coordX and coordY.

Comment: In the code you've used, what is wrong? What result are you currently seeing? It seems that all you're missing is the negative offset for the size of the image (so, location -x, -y for the image size).

Comment: I've updated the question with my current result. If i set negative offset my image goes out of screen.

Comment: You're not showing here where you coordX and coordY are being set to give you that result. However, note that those values _should be based on x and y_, so it's x/y (center) +/- cos/sin(angle).Can you show updated code with those variables being set, and noting that they should be based on x/y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having an actual, fully fleshed out answer, here's basically what you need.

```
let consume = 0.25
let x = self.frame.size.width / 2.0
let y = self.frame.size.height / 2.0
let radius = (frame.size.width - 10) / 2.0
let startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI * (-1/2))
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 - M_PI/2 * consume)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)

circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
circleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0;

let imageSize = 20.0
// Center + cos/sin(angle) * radius, then subtract half
// the image size so it will be centered on the line
let coordX: CGFloat = x + (cos(endAngle) * radius) - (imageSize / 2.0)
let coordY: CGFloat = y - (sin(endAngle) * radius) - (imageSize / 2.0)

let image = UIImage(named: "myCoolImage")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
// coordX and coordY must be at last point of UIBezierPath
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: coordX, y: coordY, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
self.addSubview(imageView)
```